# iOS: passing object to viewController error: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I have project where I'm using UINavegationController between to views:

[image]

I'm using the navigation controller because I'm using modal presentation (Flip)

But my problem is I'm trying to pass NSString Object to ViewControllerB:
Code:

```
- (IBAction)goToB:(id)sender {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToB" sender:self];
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goToB"]) {

        BViewController *vc = (BViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        vc.commigFromA = @"I'm going to B!";
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
-[UINavigationController setCommigFromA:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff1c4830c00
```

Any of you knows why or a way around this error?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Instead of solving this issue, maybe you should just redesign your app. Why have you got two navigation controllers like this? There's no need for two.

Comment: @Essenceofchickens, has been the only way I can have the navigation controller and do flip animation.

Comment: Instead of inventing your own solution, ask a new question about how you can add flip animation.

Answer (score 1):

It's crashing because the `destinationViewController` on the segue is actually a `UINavigationController`, not a `BViewController`, and `UINavigationControllers` don't know about a property `comingFromA`.  You can test this theory by replacing `prepareWithSegue` like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goToB"]) {

        UINavigationController *nvc = (UINavigationController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        BViewController *vc = (BViewController*)nvc.viewControllers[0];
        vc.commigFromA = @"I'm going to B!";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean?, can you explain ?

Comment: I added some detail

Comment: I understand. But how can you set modal transition and keep the navigation  controller?

Comment: Ahh good point, in that case, let me update my answer, you're doing it right.